# Why Opened_tables are increasing Rapidly and how to slow it down?

Tags: mysql

My opened_tables are increasing rapidly at a rate of approximately 100 tables per 5 seconds.

I have my table_cache set to 10,000, which I believe is pretty high.

MySQL performance on my website is really slow and I believe that is the reason for my site's bottlenecking.

What can I do to slow down opened_tables - I believe this is one of the reasons why my website is performing badly.

Here is mysql's process %'s: 
12.5% CPU
2.2% MEM

And my Server load:
Server load     1.70 (26 CPUs)
Memory Used     8.26% (173288 of 2097152)

This is my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
local-infile=0
set-variable = max_connections=200
safe-show-database
max_tmp_tables=1
query_cache_size=256M
query_cache_limit=128M
query_cache_type=1
key_buffer_size=256M
skip-locking
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 10000
sort_buffer_size = 1M
read_buffer_size = 768K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
thread_cache_size = 20
thread_concurrency = 4

log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
interactive_timeout=3
wait_timeout=3
connect_timeout=5
```

Comment: "My opened_tables are increasing rapidly at a rate of approximately 100 tables per 5 seconds." - erm, what?

Comment: Yes.. Open_tables  51 Opened_tables  10213 And this is at Uptime 551.. Anything over 24hours is over 1Million.

Comment: My table_cache is now set to the maximum value, and I'm still getting the rapid growth. I have no idea why!

Answer (score 0):

```
max_tmp_tables=1
```

That was the problem.

I upped that value (to 100) and Opened_tables has slowed down to hardly any increment.

I hope this helps someone!

EDIT:
Scrap That,

There is a table that is constantly Updating, Deleting and Adding new Tables.
This is to monitor users who are online.

Everytime there is an Update/Insert/Delete, a new table is Opened.

Is this Normal?

Comment: This is normal only if EXPLAIN for your query shows, that tmp table is needed to execute the query, I think.